# Calculating the division of this shape

Tags: geometry

Being given 2 circles with centres $P_1$ and $P_2$, with same radius $r$.

Lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ are the edges of the intersection between these 2 circles.

Let $A_1$ be the intersection area of the two circles between $L_2$ and $D$.

and $A_2$ the intersection area of the two circles between $L_1$ and $D$.

Given a ratio ($A_1 / A_2$) how can I calculate line $D$?

[image: Calculating line D]

Comment: Fixed it, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Wow, now I understand a little better! But it is still unclear what are your areas. You should hatch the different areas you deal with.

Comment: Added the notation for the areas to make it clear.

Comment: Good work ! Now it is very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that the midpoints of the circles are at $(\pm a,0)$ and that the line $D$ intersects the $x$-axis at $d\geq0$. The area $A_2(d)$ is a sector minus a triangle. Compute $A_2(d)$ in terms of the data. You obtain a nasty formula involving algebraic and $\arccos$ or similar terms. One then has $A_1(d)=2A_2(0)-A_2(d)$, so that the ratio $q$ in question is
$$q=q(d)={2A_0(d)-A_2(d)\over A_2(d)}\ .\tag{1}$$
Now you want to solve $(1)$ for $d$ as a function of $q$. Unfortunately this is not possible in terms of elementary functions, and yo will have to resort to numerics.